# __builtin_avr_delay_cycles implementation explanation

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, delay, avr

let's consider this simple C code compiled for atmega32 :

```
_delay_ms(1000);
```

It is translated to this assembly :

```
00000039  SER R18       Set Register 
0000003A  LDI R24,0x69      Load immediate 
0000003B  LDI R25,0x18      Load immediate 
0000003C  SUBI R18,0x01     Subtract immediate 
0000003D  SBCI R24,0x00     Subtract immediate with carry 
0000003E  SBCI R25,0x00     Subtract immediate with carry 
0000003F  BRNE PC-0x03      Branch if not equal 
00000040  RJMP PC+0x0001        Relative jump 
00000041  NOP       No operation
```

When this line :

```
_delay_ms(500);
```

Is compiled to this :

```
00000039  SER R18       Set Register 
0000003A  LDI R24,0x34      Load immediate 
0000003B  LDI R25,0x0C      Load immediate 
0000003C  SUBI R18,0x01     Subtract immediate 
0000003D  SBCI R24,0x00     Subtract immediate with carry 
0000003E  SBCI R25,0x00     Subtract immediate with carry 
0000003F  BRNE PC-0x03      Branch if not equal 
00000040  RJMP PC+0x0001        Relative jump 
00000041  NOP       No operation
```

Can someone explain the logic behind the generated assembly ? How did the developpers of the builtin assure the exact cycle delay from the `__builtin_avr_delay_cycles` function ?

EDIT : didn't mention `#define F_CPU 8000000UL` on top of file, obviously !

Comment: You probably defined or configured your MHz somewhere.

Comment: As for the rest, they just used an instruction set reference and counted the cycles.

Comment: Well, the answer I am looking for explains how `they just used an instruction set reference and counted the cycles`  !

Comment: Whats unclear with that? They literally took a [instruction set manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-0856-avr-instruction-set-manual.pdf), looked for the cycle counts of the instructions they used and summed them.

Comment: It may be obvious for you, but a per-instruction breakdown would probably give me a clue about your reasoning. Also, it seems magic numbers are involved here, maybe the way they are generated could help complete the explanation.

Comment: What magic numbers? The per-instruction break down is right there in the instruction manual.

Comment: Other delay-loop timing questions walk through the process of counting cycles, but usually they're for nested loops instead of using a 24-bit counter and sub-with-carry.  e.g. [Determine the running time of a triple nested delay loop](//stackoverflow.com/q/47840764) or [How do AVR Assembly BRNE delay loops work?](//stackoverflow.com/q/47453737), or [Calculating delay from 3 nested loops](//stackoverflow.com/q/35750663)

Comment: [Is it possible to use GCC's '\_\_builtin\_avr\_delay\_cycles' in the assembler?](//stackoverflow.com/a/13516110) shows a source-level version of the asm.  The `rjmp` and `nop` aren't part of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The AVR instruction set manual can be accessed here:

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-0856-avr-instruction-set-manual.pdf

Let's look at your code for `_delay_ms(1000);`.

The ser, ldi, and ldi instructions at the beginning take 3 cycles and set a 24-bit counter to 0x1869FF.

Then we have a loop.  Each iteration of this loop decreases the 24-bit counter by 1, and the loop terminates once the counter reaches zero.  So there will be 0x1869FF iterations of the loop.

Most iterations of the loop take 5 cycles because brne takes two cycles when it branches.  On the last iteration of the loop, brne does not branch so that last iteration only takes 4 cycles.

The two instructions after the loop take 3 cycles total.

Adding everything up, we see that the total number of cycles is:

3 + 0x1869FF*5 - 1 + 3 = 8000000

Since your CPU speed is 8 MHz, the resulting delay is 1 second.

The trick for the compiler implementers is picking how many iterations of the loop to do, how many rjmps to do after the loop, and how many nops to do after that.  Since adding iterations to the loop is free in terms of program space, you want to have as many loop iterations as possible.  Since an rjmp takes less space than two nops, you want to have as many rjmps as possible after the loop.  And then you might need one nop after that to make the cycle count correct.

For shorter delays, the compiler probably uses an 8-bit or 16-bit counter.  For really short delays, it probably just uses rjmp and nop.  For very long delays, it probably uses counters with more than 24 bits.

In some cases, it might be possible to save program space by adding a few nops inside the loop, since it might make a smaller loop counter possible or might let you remove multiple instructions at the end.  So a really smart implementation would take that into account.

Comment: Godbolt has AVR gcc installed, but unfortunately gcc4.6 is too old to support the builtin https.  The AVR built-ins page in the manual seems to be new with gcc4.8:  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/gcc/AVR-Built-in-Functions.html /  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AVR-Built-in-Functions.html.  And unfortunately clang doesn't build its AVR back-end by default, so `-target avr` doesn't work.  http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/How-do-I-call-clang-for-AVR-targets-td4058258.html

Comment: Thank you for the very clear and complete answer. What I didn't understand is the fact R18:R24:R25 holds a single, 24-bit variable that is decreased at every iteration. Looks basic, but I have to start somewhere :)

Comment: So you actually asked a question that was way more broad than it needed to be.  You asked how `__builtin_avr_delay_cycles` is implemented and that's why I wrote the last three paragraphs of my answer.  You should have said that you don't understand how the *generated assembly for the 8000000 cycle delay* works and why it is guaranteed to take 8000000 cycles.  That is definitely the first step towards understanding how `__builtin_avr_delay_cycles` might be implemented if that's what you were curious about, but it's easier to answer.